# create 3 dependent dropdown list using php ajax mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i am using PHP MYSQL and JAVASCRIP AJAX.

i have multiple  dropdown list that i want to make it dependent on each other using AJAX  where these dropdown list includes data retrieved from MYSQL database.

the user select from the **first** dropdown list and based on its selection the **second** and **third**  dropdown list display the related values.

what i have done until now is to make the second dropdown list depend on the first one.

**debug MODE:**

first pic shows the first AJAX call
[image]
Second pic shows the second AJAX call
[image]

i need now to make the second and third be depend on the first one.

tables

- site_info:

  - siteID
  - siteNAME
  - ownerID
  - companyID
- owner_info:

  - ownerID
  - ownerNAME
- company_info:

  - companyID
  - companyNAME

i know the error is in the for **each loop**

```
foreach($query_site_name as $row)
                      {
            //           $site_name = (array)$site_name;
                       echo "<option value = '".$row ->ownerID."', '".$row ->companyID."'>".$row->siteNAME."</option>";
                      }
```

how to embed 3 values in the option tag??

## code1:

```
<form method ="post" action ="" name="submit_form">
    <table border="0" width="30%">
        <tr>
           <td>Site Name</td>
           <td>Owner Name</td>
           <td>Company Name</td>
           <td>Subcontractor Name</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><select id="site_name"  name = "site_name">

             <?php


                 $query_site_name =$wpdb->get_results("select DISTINCT siteNAME, ownerID, companyID  from site_info");
                  foreach($query_site_name as $row)
                  {
        //           $site_name = (array)$site_name;
                   echo "<option value = '".$row ->ownerID."', '".$row ->companyID."'>".$row->siteNAME."</option>";
                  } 

             ?>

            <!--create  dropdown list owner names-->
            </select></td>

            <td><select id="owner_name"  name ="owner_name">
            <option value="">Select Owner</option>        
            </select></td>

            <!--create  dropdown list Company names-->


            <td><select id="Company_name"  name ="Company_name">
             <option value="">Select Company</option>       




     <script type="text/javascript">

// make Dropdownlist depend on each other
$(document).ready(function(){
// depend owner name on site name   
    $('#site_name').change(function(){
         var ownerID = $(this).val();
         $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/dropdown_fetch_owner.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{ownerID:ownerID},
            datatype:"text",
            success:function(data){
                $('#owner_name').html(data);
            }

         });

//depend company name on site name 
         var companyID = $(this).val();
         $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/dropdown_fetch_owner.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{companyID:companyID},
            datatype:"text",
            success:function(data){
                $('#Company_name').html(data);
            }

         });


      });

  });

</script>
```

where this AJAX script is used to work between the first and second dropdown list only

## dropdown_fetch_owner.php:

```
<?php
 include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wordpress/wp-load.php');
 global $wpdb;
$outputOwner = '';
$sql =$wpdb->get_results("select ownerID, ownerNAME from owner_info where ownerID = '".$_POST['ownerID']."' ORDER BY ownerNAME");
var_dump($sql);

$outputOwner= '<option value="">Select Owner</option>';
foreach($sql as $row){


    $outputOwner.= "<option value = '".$row ->ownerID."'>".$row->ownerNAME."</option>";
}
echo $outputOwner;


$outputCompany = '';
$sql =$wpdb->get_results("select companyID, companyNAME from company_info where companyID = '".$_POST['companyID']."' ORDER BY companyNAME");
var_dump($sql);

$outputCompany= '<option value="">Select Company</option>';
foreach($sql as $row){

    $outputCompany.= "<option value = '".$row ->companyID."'>".$row->companyNAME."</option>";
}
echo $outputCompany;
```

?>

thanks for advance

Comment: read this article : http://www.codexworld.com/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-php/

Answer (score 1):

Error with your ajax code in javascript try this

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$('#site_name').change(function(){

     var  arrayID    = $(this).val().split(",");
     var  ownerID    = arrayID[0];
     var  companyID  = arrayID[1];

     if(ownerID != "" && companyID != ""){

             $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/dropdown_fetch_owner.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{ownerID:ownerID},
                datatype:"text",
                success:function(data){
                    $('#owner_name').html(data);
                }

             });

             //depend company name on site name 
             $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/dropdown_fetch_owner.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{companyID:companyID},
                datatype:"text",
                success:function(data){
                    $('#Company_name').html(data);
                }

             });
    }


  });
```

});

Comment: i tried your answer did not work .
i think the problem is in the php  in first **select**  inside the for each loop in the **option tag**

Comment: if there is any error with your select query then there must be no option  inside first dropdown.

Comment: the first dropdown work perfect and i have data inside it also when i choose from the first dropdown the second display the related data.
**My Problem is concerning the third dropdown where also this third one must display the related data once the user choose from the first dropdown**.
my question is how can i include in the **option value  tag**beside **.$row ->ownerID.**  this variable **.$row ->companyID.**    


**i edit my question and add 2 picture to explain what is happen**

Comment: check my solution on top most answer hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method ="post" action ="" name="submit_form">
    <table border="0" width="30%">
        <tr>
           <td>Site Name</td>
           <td>Owner Name</td>
           <td>Company Name</td>
           <td>Subcontractor Name</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><select id="site_name"  name = "site_name">
            <option value="">selet</option>
          <option value="1,2">www.google.com</option>
            <!--create  dropdown list owner names-->
            </select></td>

            <td><select id="owner_name"  name ="owner_name">
            </select></td>

            <!--create  dropdown list Company names-->


            <td><select id="Company_name"  name ="Company_name">

         </select>
         </td>
         </tr>
         </table>
      </form>      


</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">

     $('#site_name').change(function(){
            var arrayId =   $(this).val().split(",");
        if(arrayId != ""){
            var ownerID   = arrayId[0];
            var companyID = arrayId[1];
              $.ajax({
                    url:"echo.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:{ownerID:ownerID},
                    datatype:"text",
                    success:function(data){
                        $('#owner_name').html(data);
                    }

                 });

                  //depend company name on site name 
                 $.ajax({
                    url:"echo.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:{companyID:companyID},
                    datatype:"text",
                    success:function(data){
                        $('#Company_name').html(data);
                    }

                 });
        }


      });
</script>  //ajax code in php <?php

if(isset($_POST['ownerID']))
{
$ownerID = $_POST['ownerID'];
$outputOwner = '';
$outputOwner .= '<option value="">Select Owner</option>';
$outputOwner .= '<option value="'.$ownerID.'">Test Owner</option>';
echo $outputOwner;
}
if(isset($_POST['companyID']))
{

$companyID = $_POST['companyID'];
$outputCompany = '';
$outputCompany .= '<option value="">Select Company</option>';
$outputCompany.= '<option value="'.$companyID.'">Test Comapny</option>';
echo $outputCompany;
}
 ?>
```

Comment: this answer did not work also i got the result of the **owner name droplist** but in the **company name** i got nothing

Comment: this is working code all you need to do is modify echo.php file according to your query

Comment: in the debug mode it shows that the parameters are correct but on the webpage the third dropdown list doesn't display anything